# ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)

Tags: ldap, fedora

i have a problem with ldap configuration :

```
$ ldapadd -x -D 'cn=Manager,dc=ircoms,dc=com' -f file.ldif -W 
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

i deleted the contains of `/var/lib/ldap` ,then execute

ldapadd -x -D 'cn=Manager,dc=ircoms,dc=com' -f file.ldif -W

Now I get this error:

```
$ ldapadd -x -D 'cn=Manager,dc=ircoms,dc=com' -f file.ldif 
ldap_bind: Server is unwilling to perform (53) 
additional info: unauthenticated bind (DN with no password) disallowed
```

I work on fedora 15.

Answer (score 1):

`invalid credentials` indicates that 1) the password you typed was incorrect or 2) the server is configured to return `invalid credentials` even when some other problem prevented authentication, for example, if the authorization identity does not exist in the directory database. In the 2d example, you attempted to authenticate with a bind request that contained a distinguished name but no password, which the directory server disallowed.